# Best practice, import data feed and download image on every row with PHP as fast as possible

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple CSV files (150k-500k lines for now) with data I want to import to my MySQL DB.

This is my workflow at the moment:

1. Import files to a temporary table in db (raw lines)
2. Select one line at the time, explode it to an array, clean it up and import it.

Every item has an image, and I download it using curl. After downloading it I resize it with codeigniters resizer (gd2). Both this steps are absolutely necessary, and takes time. I want (need) to delete and reimport fresh files daily to keep the content fresh.

The reason for the temporary db save was to se if I could spawn multiple instances of the import script with crontab. This didn’t give me the results that I wanted.

Do you have any design ideas on how I can do this in a “fast” way?

The site is running on a 4GB 1.8 Ghz Dual core dedicated server.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are looking at "spawning multiple instances of the import script" you should potentially look at http://www.gearman.org and how to set up job servers for processing data.

Comment: Thanks cillosis, I will check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a feature called `LOAD DATA INFILE` which does exactly what it sounds like you're trying to do.

From the question, it's not clear whether you're using it already or not? But even if you are, it sounds like you could improve the way you're doing it.

A SQL script like this could work for you:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE filename.csv
INTO table tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(
  field1,
  field2,
  field3,
  @var1,
  @var2,
  etc
)
SET
  field4 = @var1 / 100,
  field5 = (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE name=@var2 LIMIT 1),
  etc
```

That's a fairly complex example, showing how you can import your CSV data directly into your table, and manipulate it into the correct format all in one go.

The great thing about this is that it's actually very quick. We use this to import a 500,000 record file on a weekly basis, and it is several orders of magnitude faster than a PHP program that would read the file and write to the DB. We do run it from a PHP program, but PHP isn't responsible for any of the importing; MySQL does everything itself from the one query.

In our case, even though we do manipulate the import data a lot, we still write it to a temp table, as we have about a dozen further processing steps before it goes into the master table. But in your case it sounds like this method may save you from having to use a temp table at all.

MySQL manual page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

As for downloading the images, I'm not sure how you could speed that up, other than keeping an eye on which of the imported records have been updated, and only fetching the images for the records that have changed. But I'm guessing if that's a viable solution then you're probably doing it already.

Still, I hope the MySQL suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thorough answer. I'm not using the LOAD DATA INFILE function, I will give it a go. I need to manipulate the data from each CSV because there are multiple suppliers with just a tiny bit different structure in each file. Sadly enough I think the images is the real bottle neck and they're also the primary information :(

Answer (score 1):

The fastest thing to do is use threading.

I would suggest two Workers, one with a connection to MySQL and one to download and resize your images, open the CSV, read it using fgets or whatever, with each line, create a Stackable that will insert into the database, pass that stackable to another that will download the file ( and know the ID of the row where the data is stored ) and resize it. You might want to employ more than one worker for images ...

http://docs.php.net/Worker

http://docs.php.net/Stackable

http://docs.php.net/Thread

(be sure to reference docs.php.net, the docs build is a little behind)

http://pthreads.org (a basic breakdown of how things work to be found on index)

http://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads (windows downloads available here if you want to test locally )

http://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads (last release is a little out of date)